# Get all paths between the source and destination nodes in PostGIS using PGRouting extension

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

How to get all paths between the source and destination nodes in PostGIS using PGRouting extension?

I tried the functions:

- `pgr_edgeDisjointPaths`: It returns only the Disjoint paths.([40,41,42,45],[40,39,43,47,46,45])
- `pgr_bdDijkstra`: It returns only the shortest path. ([40,41,42,45])

Is there any other function available to accomplish the desired result.

I want all the paths between the nodes 40 and 45 such as ([40,41,42,45],[40,39,43,47,46,45],[40,39,43,42,45] and so on), from the network mentioned in the screenshot below.

[image: SampleNetwork]

Comment: In your example there is an infinite number of possible paths because your system has a loop. 40,[41,42,43,39,40]*, 41,42,45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get it with this function: [pgr_KSP](https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_KSP.html).

It gets you the K shortest paths. If you put a really high number, it should gets you all the possible path.